# adding @ symbol in angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

My API is returning something like

@something : 'value'

when I add

```
  <li class="air-con" ng-if="{{c.Somthing['@something']}}">Air Con</li>
```

I get a $parse:syntax error, it seems like the @ symbol is breaking the code is there another way I can excess this value

Comment: Use single quotes around the @something ('@something').

Comment: still the same error

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the purpose of your @ variable name?

Comment: You could change your architecture slightly to build an object representing your API response rather than blindly feeding into your ap whatever it returns. Then you can rename the offending property.

Comment: I don't have the luxury sadly : (

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why is it, as far as I know @ is used in directives, but as  a workaround:

In controller just copy the value:

```
$scope.myval = c.Somthing['@something']
```

and use

```
<li class="air-con" ng-if="{{myval}}">Air Con</li>
```